# 2D game socket server and client

Tags: java, swing, sockets

Hey guys I'm trying to work with sockets to implements a multiplayer aspect to a game I'm starting. I created the code using some tutorials that i found. I understand the basic concepts, but am having trouble trying to think of ways to have two separate players, and sending all their data to the client and server.

here's the test server class that I created (just sends a string):

```
package Server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public void Start() throws IOException{
        String clientSentence;
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8877);

        while(true){
            Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
            BufferedReader fromClient = 
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = fromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("MSG from client: " + clientSentence);
            toClient.writeBytes("Sending back: "+ clientSentence);
            socket.close();
            fromClient.close();
            toClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the client code:

```
package Client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public void Start() throws Exception{
        String sentence;
        String modified;
        BufferedReader fromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8877);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = fromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
        modified = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("From Server: " + modified);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Would I send over the data as objects? Or would I send each variable separately as their integer values?

Thanks!

Comment: Game networking is a broad topic. Generally games do not use serialization. You should also use UDP not TCP (java.net.Socket is TCP)

Comment: I would also suggest googling threaded networking for your server.

Comment: Ok I looked at UDP, but how should I send every variable over?

Comment: You need to send what you need to send. Only you know that. It's your system. We can't see it.